# Есть два списка, из них надо собрать один словарь

Tags: python

Есть два списка, из них надо собрать словарь.
В данном словаре ключом должен быть интерфейс (Например, 'Po1'), а значением должен быть другой словарь с ключами mac-address и description, которые берутся из списков. Значение ключа mac-address должен быть список, потому что их может быть много на одном порту.

```
Список интерфейсов и дескрипшенов:

 [['Po1', 'Server-001'],
 ['Po2', 'Server-002'],
 ['Po3', 'Server-003'],
 ['Po4', 'Server-004']]

Список маков и интерфейсов:

[['b8ce.f67c.b616', 'Po18'],
 ['b8ce.f67c.b6c6', 'Po21'],
 ['b8ce.f67c.b6d2', 'Po19'],
 ['b8ce.f67c.b812', 'Po22'],
 ['b8ce.f684.27ee', 'Po17']]
```

Нужно видеть что-то вроде:
{'Po1': {'mac-address': [mac1, mac2, ..., mac20]',
'description': XXXX,
}}

Использую для этого конструкция вида:

```
result_dict = defaultdict(dict)
for i,j in zip_longest(dict(res_list).items(), dict(res_desc_list).items()):
     result_dict[i[1]]['mac-address'] = [].append(i[0])
     result_dict[i[1]]['descriotion'] = j[1]
```

Но спотыкаюсь на этапе пополнения списка мак-адресов для каждого из интерфейсов. Как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не до конца понял задачу, но мой вариант таков:

```
list_1 = [
    ['Po1', 'Server-001'],
    ['Po2', 'Server-002'],
    ['Po3', 'Server-003'],
    ['Po4', 'Server-004']
]

list_2 = [
    ['b8ce.f67c.b616', 'Po18'],
    ['b8ce.f67c.b6c6', 'Po21'],
    ['b8ce.f67c.b6d2', 'Po19'],
    ['b8ce.f67c.b812', 'Po22'],
    ['b8ce.f684.27ee', 'Po17']
]

result = {info[0]: {"mac-address": [], "description": info[1]} for info 
in list_1}
for mac_address, interface in list_2:
    try:
        result[interface]["mac-address"].append(mac_address)
    except KeyError:
        result[interface] = {"mac-address": [], "description": None}

print(result)
```

Comment: макадресов может быть много для одного интерфейса. 
В list_2 может быть пот так:
 ['1111.aaaa.bbbb', 'Po18'], ['b8ce.cccc.aaaa', 'Po18'], ['abab.ffff.caca', 'Po18'],
В вашем примере для Po18 запишется последний мак адрес, если не ошибаюсь. А нужно чтобы записались все

Comment: Понял. Поправил

Answer (score 3):

Если уж используете `defaultdict`, то можно так:

```
from collections import defaultdict

servers = [['Po1', 'Server-001'],
           ['Po2', 'Server-002'],
           ['Po3', 'Server-003'],
           ['Po4', 'Server-004']]

macs = [['b8ce.f67c.b616', 'Po18'],
        ['b8ce.f67c.b812', 'Po04'],
        ['b8ce.f67c.b6c6', 'Po21'],
        ['b8ce.f67c.b6d2', 'Po19'],
        ['ffff.dead.beef', 'Po19'],
        ['b8ce.f67c.b812', 'Po22'],
        ['b8ce.f684.27ee', 'Po17']]

result = defaultdict(lambda: {'mac-address': [], 'description': ''})
for intf, srv in servers:
    result[intf]['description'] = srv
for mac, intf in macs:
    result[intf]['mac-address'].append(mac)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно чтобы ключи итогового словаря были из первого списка, а значения из второго, то попробуйте так:

```
serv = [
    ['Po1', 'Server-001'],
    ['Po2', 'Server-002'],
    ['Po3', 'Server-003'],
    ['Po4', 'Server-004']]

m_adr = [
    ['b8ce.f67c.b616', 'Po1'],
    ['b8ce.f67c.b6c6', 'Po21'],
    ['b8ce.f67c.b6d2', 'Po19'],
    ['b8ce.f67c.b812', 'Po22'],
    ['b8ce.f684.27ee', 'Po1']]

m_adr_dict = {}
for adr, intr in m_adr:
    m_adr_dict[intr] = m_adr_dict.get(intr,[]) + [adr]
res = {intr: {'description': descr, 
              'mac-address': m_adr_dict.get(intr)} 
       for intr, descr in serv}

res
'''
{'Po1': {'description': 'Server-001',
         'mac-address': ['b8ce.f67c.b616', 'b8ce.f684.27ee']},
 'Po2': {'description': 'Server-002', 'mac-address': None},
 'Po3': {'description': 'Server-003', 'mac-address': None},
 'Po4': {'description': 'Server-004', 'mac-address': None}}
```